# How to update jsf datatable from back bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a form that user should enter some values to get some info from a web service. Firstly user fulfills the form and then as he clicks the request button webservice is called. Until here everything works nicely. But as the webservice returns the info, I have to re-render the datatable with the new data. Here is my page:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formCus">
        <h:outputLabel value="Müşteri Tipi: *"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="customerType" value="#{customerService.musteriTipi}" style="width: 39%">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=" " />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bireysel" itemValue="BIREYSEL" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tüzel" itemValue="TUZEL" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yabancı" itemValue="YABANCI" />
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.musteriTipi}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputLabel value="Ad/Firma Adı: *" for="customerName" />
        <p:inputText id="customerName" value="#{customerService.adFirmaAdi}" title="Müşteri adı." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.adFirmaAdi}" />
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="Soyad/Ünvan: *" for="customerSurname" />
        <p:inputText id="customerSurname" value="#{customerService.soyadUnvan}" title="Müşteriye ait soyad/ünvan." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.soyadUnvan}" />
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="TC Kimlik No: *"  />
        <p:inputText id="customerTC" value="#{customerService.tcKimlikNo}" title="TC Kimlik numarasını buraya girin.TC numarası sadece sayılardan oluşmalıdır." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.tcKimlikNo}" partialSubmit="true" process="@this"/>
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="Vergi No:"  />
        <p:inputText id="customerVergi" value="#{customerService.vergiNo}" title="TC Kimlik numarasını buraya girin.TC numarası sadece sayılardan oluşmalıdır." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.vergiNo}" partialSubmit="true"/>
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="Müdürlük Kodu: *" />
        <p:inputText id="departmantId" value="#{customerService.mudurlukKodu}" title="Müdürlük kodunu buraya girin.Müdürlük kodu sadece sayılardan oluşmalıdır." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.mudurlukKodu}" partialSubmit="true"/>
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="Müşteri Kodu: " />
        <p:inputText id="customerId" value="#{customerService.musteriKodu}" title="Müdürlük kodunu buraya girin.Müdürlük kodu sadece sayılardan oluşmalıdır." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.musteriKodu}" />
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputLabel value="E-Posta Adresi: " />
        <p:inputText id="customerMail" value="#{customerService.mail}" title="Müşteriye ait e-mail adresini buraya girin." >
            <p:ajax event="change" update="#{customerService.mail}" partialSubmit="true"/>
        </p:inputText>

        <h:outputText value=" "/>
        <p:commandButton id="query" value="Müşteri Sorgula" actionListener="#{customerService.request}" async="true"  onsuccess="panelwv.show()">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":personList" ></f:ajax> 
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGrid columns="5">
        <h:outputText value=""/>
        <h:outputText value=""/>
        <p:panel widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false" closable="true" header="Sorgu Yapılıyor...">
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />  
        </p:panel>
        <h:outputText value=""/>
        <h:outputText value=""/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="Bulunan Müşterilere Ait Bilgiler:" />


    <h:form id="personList" rendered="#{not empty customerService.musteriKodu}">
        <p:dataTable value="#{customerService.customer}" var="item" id="persontable" emptyMessage="Henüz müşteri eklemediniz.">
            <p:column headerText="Müşteri/Firma ID">
                #{item.customerId}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Ad/Firma Adı">
                #{item.customerName}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Soyad/Ünvan" >
                #{item.customerSurname}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Müşteri Tipi" >
                #{item.customerType} 
            </p:column> 
            <p:column headerText="Telefon" >
                #{item.customerTel}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Adres">
                #{item.customerAddress}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="E-Posta">
                #{item.customerMail}
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And here is my back bean:

```
//some getter and setters
List<Customers> customer = new ArrayList<Customers>();

public List<Customers> getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(List<Customers> customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public String request() {

    final RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    //System.out.println("Progress...");

          //musteriSorgula(musteriSorgulaKriter());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                musteriKodu = String.valueOf(musteriSorgula(musteriSorgulaKriter()).getMusteriBilgisi().getMusteriKodu());
                List<TelefonBilgisi> tel_result = telefonSorgula(telefonSorgulaKriter(musteriKodu)).getMusteriTelefonListesi();
                //telefon = tel_result.getMusteriTelefonListesi().get(0).getTelefonNo();

                if (tel_result.size() > 0) {
                    for (TelefonBilgisi t : tel_result) {
                        telefon = t.getTelefonNo();
                    }
                } else {
                    telefon = "No telephone.";
                }
                List<UavtAdresBilgisi> uavt_result = uavtAdresSorgula(uavtAdresSorgulaKriter(musteriKodu)).getMusteriUavtAdresListesi();

                if (uavt_result.size() > 0) {
                    for (UavtAdresBilgisi u : uavt_result) {
                        adres = String.valueOf(u.getSehir()) + ", " + String.valueOf(u.getBucak()) + ", " + String.valueOf(u.getKasaba());
                    }
                } else {
                    adres = "No address.";
                }


                Customers cust = new Customers(musteriTipi, BigInteger.valueOf(Long.valueOf(musteriKodu)), adFirmaAdi, soyadUnvan, telefon, adres, mail, projectId);
                if (!customer.contains(cust)) {
                    customer.add(cust);
                    System.out.println("Customer has been added.");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Customer is still in the list.");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CustomerService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                context.execute("alert('Try again.')");
            }
        }
    }).start();

    context.execute("panelwv.close()");
    return "";
}
```

The back bean could connect to webservice and gether the info, I can see that in the logs. In the beginning my datatable is empty. What I want is to show the new data as the webservice responses. `context.update("personList")` doesn't work when I place it below:

```
customer.add(cust);
```

If someone could help me I would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Could you try to add `update=:personList` into your command button which runs the query.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. update= :personList tries to update it immediately as the button is clicked. But it doesn't update the datatable. It is because the delay of webservice request.

Comment: Then use `oncomplete="updater();"` for that button and insert `p:remoteCommand name="updater" update=":personList"` that will work after web service job is completed.

Comment: @Ömer Isn't that going to call the updater right after the original button request handling has finished? If so, then there is a race condition as the webservice may take longer to respond.

Comment: @dratewka When the commandbutton action listener is called oncomplete is going to wait till action completed, server is not going to return until web service response comes I guess.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı not really - the webservice is called here in a separate thread, so the server won't wait unless you tell it to using `thread.join()` and this could be done in the original `request()` method without the need for an extra `p:remoteCommand`. But this may mean that the request will take some time to complete (depending on the webservice) and the user will be waiting and wondering...

Comment: @dratewka I got it, thread syncronizing can  solve

Answer (score 1):

```
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":personList" ></f:ajax>
```

Make a change as

```
        <f:ajax execute="@form" update="persontable" render=":personList" ></f:ajax>
```

Comment: it says: 'The attribute update is not defined in the component ajax'

Comment: Sorry I meant to say         <p:ajax execute="@form" update="persontable" render=":personList" ></p:ajax>

Comment: This time it says the same same thing for execute and render components.

Comment: no, still doesn't work. Now I am gving it a try with valueChangeListener.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29492/discussion-between-makky-and-ali-yucel-akgul)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what you want to do is to force the client to update the data table from your server. Take a look at [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) and [push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and also (if you don't need to support older browsers) [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

If you google around you'll find tutorials on how to do it using JSF. And as you are using Primefaces, not that this library has comet support: checkout `p:push` and `atmosphere` support.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using RemoteCommand component as @Ömer said.

Try use it at the end of the thread(inside the thread braces) with context.execute("updater();");

Comment: Sorry you're rigth. Secondly you can use <p:poll> I tried on a small application

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easy to solve if you use RichFaces

Comment: well I have to do it in primefaces.